# How to Blame a particular revision in vim-fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

vim fugitive's Gblame is very good. Gblame annotates the current file and offers keyboard shortcuts like P, which annotates the parent-revision of the file form the blame window.

However, if i want to annotate a specific revision of a file, how do i do that?

I wish there was some thing like

```
:Gblame <commit-id>
```

That would blame the current file as of the given commit-id..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:Gedit` to view the current file at a certain commit and then run `:Gblame`

```
:Gedit <commit-id>:%
:Gblame
```

We use `%` to represent the current file's name.

For more help see:

```
:h fugitive-:Gblame
:h fugitive-:Gedit
:h fugitive-revision
:h cmdline-special
:h :_%
```